# Why my scraping with Selenium is not working on Digital Ocean droplet?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, digital-ocean

I'm working with Digital Ocean and droplets for the first time, and I can't get my Selenium script to work. At first I was getting the `DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist` error, however, now my script is just not returning anything. It's not actually finishing at all. I tried adding ports and  specifying locations of the chromium-browser. And nothing seems to be working.

This is my code:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/home/username/myproject')
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

base_url = 'https://www.wikipedia.org/'
driver.get(base_url)

table_rows = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".footer-sidebar-text")
text = table_rows.text
print(text)
driver.quit()
```

For context, if it helps, the code works locally with just this:

```
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
```

What do I need to do to fix this? Thank you!

**EDIT:** Just to add a note for anyone having the same issue. Follow Barry's code below. But before that, make sure your droplet has enough memory, so Chrome can be installed properly. I had to resize mine to 1GB memory and that solved the issues and errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure Chrome or Chromium is installed, if not install it with apt, or download/wget it and install it.

Then do:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium-browser" ### you should be able to remove this, Selenium should use the default location
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/home/username/myproject') ## this, I'm not sure about, I cannot debug it
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Selenium documentation can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).
EDIT:
To install a non-snap version of chrome:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Then

```
apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Hi, Barry! Thank you for your answer. I'm getting a "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable" error now. I have chromium installed, and when I type in "which chromium" the path I'm getting is "/snap/bin/chromium". And user-data-dir is the location of my project, hopefully the path is specific enough.

Comment: Oh and "chromium-browser --version" is giving me "Chromium 119.0.6045.199 snap", too. Just for further context, if needed.

Comment: You should download chrome .deb package and install it, and it should work. (First wget it, then install it with `apt`).

Comment: I'm so sorry if this is another dumb question, but where do I find the latest package? Do I just type in "wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb" and it'll be enough?

Comment: No worries @hemoglobin, i updated my answer. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still getting the "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable", but I appreciate all your help. I'm going to attempt to start with a new droplet and apply all you said.

Comment: Returning to accept this answer because after I resized my droplet (lack of memory was the issue), I was able to install Chrome properly. And this worked out perfectly. Thank you so much, Barry!

Answer (score 0):

Please add **disable-dev-shm-usage** argument

```
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

Comment: Hi, Rahmberg. Thanks, but it still won't execute anything, even with that addition. What am I missing here?